# breaking columns using substring

Tags: sql-server-2008

i am having long string in column as a full name of the employee , i want to break that down in first name, middle name and last name. for example i am having `Andrade, Maria Sandra` (lname,(space)fname(space)mname)breaking will be like 
fname =Maria, lname= Andrade and middle name like Sandra.

My column generally have lname,fname.

i am able to divide lname, but not correct breaking for fname and mname

```
  SELECT  EmployeeName as [full name  ], SUBSTRING( EmployeeName,CHARINDEX(',',EmployeeName)+1,LEN(EmployeeName)) as[First name ]
  ,SUBSTRING( EmployeeName,0,CHARINDEX(',',EmployeeName)) [Last Name]
 , SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING( EmployeeName,CHARINDEX(',',EmployeeName)+1,LEN(EmployeeName)),CHARINDEX(' ',EmployeeName),LEN (SUBSTRING( EmployeeName,CHARINDEX(',',EmployeeName),LEN(EmployeeName)))) as[Middle  name ]
 FROM test$`
```

Comment: this has been asked 100 times and there is no 100% fool proof method. What if there is a JR, what if there is a III, what if there is two middle names? what if there are two last names as is common in many cultures?... etc. Any effort to do this just complicates the problem later. Normalize your data and avoid this in the future

Comment: for now i just need to break that down and if any particular case then i will fix it manually.

Comment: Now that methodology goes against every paradigm of programming.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perfect reason why you should normalize your data.

```
declare @table table(thename varchar(500))
insert into @table
values
('Andrade, Maria Sandra'),
('Andrade, Maria'),
('Andrade, Maria Sandra OhSnap')

select
    left(thename,CHARINDEX(',',thename) - 1) as LastName
    ,substring(thename,charindex(' ',thename),case when charindex(' ',thename) + charindex(' ',reverse(thename)) > len(thename) then charindex(' ',reverse(thename))  else len(thename) - (charindex(' ',thename) + charindex(' ',reverse(thename))) + 1 end) as FirstName
    ,case when charindex(' ',thename) + charindex(' ',reverse(thename)) - 1 = len(thename) then null else right(thename,charindex(' ',reverse(thename))) end as MiddleName
from @table
```